# Is possible to have one project with a settings file where i can put the splash and icon i want because is for a multiple app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

What i want, if it is possible to have one project with different splash screens and logos and icons that can be setted as variables in a settings file something like that is what i looking for if it is posible or otherwise i would have to have multiple projects, i mean different folders to apps that varely are different just the images(splash, icon). I have a ionic 3 project by the way.

I have tried use a build-extras.grandle file inside platforms/android , i know it works for phonegap but i could not make it work for ionic. This is the code i use:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    app1 {
      applicationIdSuffix ".app1"
    }
    app2 {
      applicationIdSuffix ".app2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with this code in build.gradle that is inside platforms/android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        espatolero {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appName: "E y L inmobiliaria", launcherName: "Espatolero y Lorenzo", icon:"icon"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".espatolero"
            resValue "string", "zone", "Buzios"
            resValue "string", "languages", "pt,es,en"
        }

        ardizzone {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appName: "Ardizzone",launcherName: "Ardizzone inmobiliaria", icon:"icondebug"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".ardizzone"
            resValue "string", "zone", "Cabo Frío"
            resValue "string", "languages", "pt,es,en"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFileName = new File(output.outputFileName, "clientapp-${variant.name}.apk")
        }
    }
```

And in your code you put this:

```
if (window.cordova) {
   cordova.getAppResources.getResources('zone').then((zone) => {
     console.log("ZONE", zone)
     //Buzios or Cabo frio
    });
}
```

Also you need to install this plugins with cordova plugin add nameOfThePlugin :

```
cordova-plugin-app-version
cordova-plugin-app-resources
```